# how to get form data in angular 4 with array of objects

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

This is my angular 4 form code. but it not works. how to handle this ? ERROR `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.` help me to solve this.

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="processForm()">
      <div class="form group">
          <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.id">
      </div>
      <div class="form group">
          <label for="fname">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.fname">
      </div>
      <div class="form group">
          <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.lname">
      </div>
      <div class="form group">
          <label for="age">Age</label>
          <input type="text" name="age" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.age">
      </div>
      <div class="form group">
          <label for="mobile_number">Mobile_Number</label>
          <input type="text" name="mobile_number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.phone[0].mobile_number">
       </div>
      <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-success">
  </form>
</div> 

export class User {
    id:Number;
    age:Number;
    fname:string;
    lname:string;
    phone:Phone[];
}

export class Phone{
    pid:Number;
    mobile_number:Number;
}
```

This is the error i'm getting in the console

```
UserFormComponent.html:17 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (UserFormComponent.html:21)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13067)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12251)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12531)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12257)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12557)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12252)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
```

Comment: paste the exception and the code related to it.

Comment: Also, when do you observe the `TypeError` (i.e. when you load a page, when you take a certain action)?  And where does the error occur (i.e. in your browser's JS console?).

Comment: It works but the json object contains values only for                                        User {fname: "asadd", lname: "wdwokj", age: "22"}

Comment: @annamalaikumaran - so you want to hide phone if it not present in object or is there issue with data because i am not seeing any code which retrives data here

Comment: check you serverside code and ts code that you are getting phone as part of object or not, please do accept/upvote answer if worked for you

Answer (score 0):

you have to try like this

```
<input type="text" name="mobile_number" 
  class="form-control" 
   [(ngModel)]="user.phone && user.phone[0].mobile_number">
```