# how to get form data in angular 9 with array of objects[Updated question on July-29-2020]

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-forms

This is my angular 9 form code. but it not works. how to handle this ? ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'mobile_number' of undefined. help me to solve this.

```
    <form (ngSubmit)="processForm()">
<section *ngFor="let user of users;let i=index">
          <div class="form group">
              <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.id">
          </div>
          <div class="form group">
              <label for="fname">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.fname">
          </div>
          <div class="form group">
              <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.lname">
          </div>
          <div class="form group">
              <label for="age">Age</label>
              <input type="text" name="age" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.age">
          </div>
          <div class="form group">
              <label for="mobile_number">Mobile_Number</label>
              <input type="text" name="mobile_number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.phone && user.phone[0].mobile_number">
           </div>
          <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-success">
</section>
      </form>
```

I had created classes something like this:

```
export class User {
constructor(
public id:Number,
public age:Number,
public  fname:string, 
public lname:string,
public  phone:Phone[]){}
}

export class Phone{
constructor(
public pid:Number,
public mobile_number:Number){}
}
```

How can i assign ngModel for input filed with these type of classes

(Below answer I had seen it from stackoverflow [how to get form data in angular 4 with array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915807/how-to-get-form-data-in-angular-4-with-array-of-objects/63134103#63134103) answers but it is throwing error like mobile_number is undefined)

```
<input type="text" name="mobile_number" 
  class="form-control" 
   [(ngModel)]="user.phone && user.phone[0].mobile_number">
Can someone help me with this?
```

My typescript file:

```
users:User[]=[new User(null,null,null,null,[])];
```

Comment: looks like the phone array in the user object is empty

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface for your User type

```
export interface Phone{
     pid:Number;
    mobile_number:Number;
    }
    
    export interface User {
    
     id:Number;
     age:Number;
      fname:string; 
     lname:string;
      phone:Phone[];
    }
```

And create an object of type User to hold the values

```
public user = {} as User;
```

[CheckThis](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-driven-form-validation-njsp8m)

Comment: It is throwing an error while updating my answer with above suggestion.Template parse errors:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 112

Comment: I had updated the question sorry that's my mistake can have a look at it again.

Comment: @dattaambareesh Check the link I provided.

Comment: Thank you so much for that but I want something like I updated in question just a few minutes ago because I was instructed to do only in that way.

Comment: @dattaambareesh Updated the code in stackBlits. Now I used the same class you created for it.

Comment: But I am defining user object as an array because I may have more than 1 user details in the  form does updated code work for that?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to edit only one phone number? No need for an array.

If you want to edit multiple phone numbers you could try something like this:

```
<div class="form group" *ngFor="let phone of user.phone; index as i;">
    <label for="mobile_number">Mobile_Number {{i+1}}</label>
    <input type="text" name="mobile_number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="phone.mobile_number">
</div>
```

Add an "add" button and fill the phone array with an new phone object.

Comment: But what if I want to perform form validation for Mobile number 2 because we cannot use template reference variable like #mobile_nuber{{i+1}}="ngModel" because it's throwing me errors or Is there any way.Can you suggest me.